# @NotNull and @NotEmpty for same property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I am using spring boot.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
```

For same property I am giving two annotations one is for null check another is for empty check.

```
@NotNull(message = "{email.notnull}")
@NotEmpty(message = "{email.notempty}")
private String email;
```

I am loading the error messages from properties file.

When I give email as **empty** then I am getting the error message from `email.notempty` only, but when I give email as null then `email.notnull` and `email.notempty` these two error messages are displaying, May I Know what is the mistake that I have done.

I should be able to see only null error when I have given null.

Comment: Because javax.validation will execute all validators for a given field. So both validators will be executed. Ditch the `@NotNull` and just leave the `@NotEmpty`.

Comment: a field (e.g. CharSequence, Collection, Map, or Array) constrained with @NotEmpty must be not null and its size/length must be greater than zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [`@NotEmpty` documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty.html) states

> The annotated element must not be null nor empty.

It has an implicit not null requirement so you can drop `@NotNull`.

See also [Difference Between @NotNull, @NotEmpty, and @NotBlank Constraints in Bean Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank)